# How to loop Multiple UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

I intended to make new position of my UIButton Frame by using loop but I got no luck, here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


for (var i = 75 ; i <= 275; ++i) {
        let marginLoopButton: CGFloat = 175.0
        let widthLoopButton = view.bounds.width - 2 * marginLoopButton
        let marginYLoopButton: CGFloat = 295.0
        let minimalYLoopButton = view.bounds.maxY - 2 * marginYLoopButton
        self.loopButtonTwo.frame = CGRect(x: i, y: minimalYLoopButton, width: widthLoopButton, height: 70)
        self.loopButtonTwo.setTitle("Orange", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(self.loopButtonTwo)
    }
}
```

so the first button position will be different than the second button. The problem is : `self.loopButtonTwo.frame = CGRect(x: i, y: minimalYLoopButton, width: widthLoopButton, height: 70)` When I put the `i` on `x:` Xcode gives me error message : "Cannot invoke initializer for type CGRect with an argument list of type (x: int, y:CGFloat, width"

and also how to multiply the number in swift? I know in C we just write `for (i = 75 ; i <= 275; +=10){}` but how to write in swift?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: is the view using auto-layout?

Comment: i think this code will not do what you are intending, are you trying to animate a button moving? if thats the case you need to use a `UIView.animate...`  method

Comment: @trojanfoe not at all

Comment: The question is really about casting and `for` loops in swift and nothing to do with `UIButton`s.

Comment: @Fonix I also intending to animate it too  but I know how to animate the UIButton and jason Nam' s code what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast i to CGFloat.

```
self.loopButtonTwo.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i), y: minimalYLoopButton, width: widthLoopButton, height: 70)
```

Comment: Please select my answer, that would be very helpful for me :)